# How may I determine a type of an object at the screen(pygame)?

Tags: python, pygame

The point is I need to find out what type of object is at (x, y)

```
def choose_target(self, screen):
    for y in range(-tower_range, tower_range + 1):
        for x in range(-tower_range, tower_range + 1):
            if screen[self.x + x, self.y + y] is Enemy:
                self.target = screen[self.x + x, self.y + y]
```

I thought it should be like this but it turned up I can't get information from the `screen`. Also how may make my tower remember a target? Now, I am not sure about this `self.target = screen[self.x + x, self.y + y]` as well.

Comment: I am not 100% certain this is the solution hence why I am not posting this as an answer, but you should consider looping through your objects in the game world and checking if the (x, y) point collides with their rectangles: `object.rect.collidepoint(x, y)`. If true, you can then check if the _object_ is of type `Enemy`. You need to get the information from your collection of objects in the game world (where ever you store that). Let me know if that helps or if you have any further questions.

Comment: It looks like it has helped(haven't tested it yet, but now it doesnt end up with an error) but It sounds complicated, I mean now I have one more nested loop. Guess, have to change the logic.

Comment: UPD: It works. Thanks a lot

Comment: you are very welcome. I will change it to an answer. If you feel it is worth an upvote, would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to pinpoint an object within the screen space (a common way to do that is 'ray casting'), check for a collision against objects in the game world.

To do that, loop through the objects in the game world and check if the (x, y) point collides with the objects bounding boxes (rects) like so: `object.rect.collidepoint(pos)`.

If *true*, you can then check if the object is of type `Enemy`.